# Virtualbox guest in NAT mode cannot access hosts by name on the local network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns, nat

I have a virtualbox guest in NAT mode which cannot seem to resolve hosts on the local LAN. I can get to them by IP, but not by hostname. I realize that switching it into bridged mode would probably resolve the issue. But aside from that, is there a way to get the NAT guest to resolve hosts on the local network? I've been unable to find anything on superuser/stackoverflow/google that indicates how to do this. The solution offered in this post (https://superuser.com/a/722670/911319) did not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Both host and guest are Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You can always try setting up a local DNS server.